# To install Microsoft office in 25 machines

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation

i need to install Microsoft Office in 25 machines which are in a domain.Is their any way to do that at once. It's really hectic to install in all machines individua;ly.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is.

- GPO rollout via AD Group policy.
- Any of the software mainteannce tools that are plenty for profesional admins.

I would suggst using a group policy and just publish it.

Answer (score 1):

The volume licensed editions of Microsoft Office, at least, allow you to create an MSP to do unattended installs. You can then roll this out using the software delivery mechanism of your choice - Group Policy, SCCM, Altiris etc.